# Show different img for different display sizes and only download the visible one

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular9

I'm using the following html on a component in Angular to show a thumbnail image based on the users screen size.

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <img class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block d-lg-block img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="api/thumbnail/{{auctionListItem.thumbnailId}}/240/150/thumbnail.jpg">
  <img class="d-lg-none d-md-none img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="api/thumbnail/{{auctionListItem.thumbnailId}}/400/300/thumbnail.jpg">
</div>
```

On smaller screens the picture takes up the whole width of the page and for these users I show a bigger picture. I could also solve this by only having the bigger picture and scaling it to fit for all users. But that would use unneeded bandwidth for about 50% of the sites visitors.

My problem right now though is that BOTH pictures are being downloaded for everyone.

So my question is, is there a CSS solution to tell the browser to only download the visible image, if not what would be the best way to solve this with angular? Do i need to get the pages width and use `*ngIf` to hide the image tag not being used?

Comment: If you're using .NET, I suggest use PhotoSauce.MagicScaler https://github.com/saucecontrol/PhotoSauce or similar. You can has a API that you give an URL and a width and received the data. This allow you only has one image in server

Comment: I've already built an API and as you can see in the urls above I just tell it what size picture I want, this however does not solve the problem as I want to change the size based on the users screen size.

Comment: using  the jburtondev answer, you can has a variable "size" `[src]="'api/thumbnail/'+auctionListItem.thumbnailId+'/'+size"`make the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with CSS as you noted, however you can do this with Angular by changing the src property dynamically. You'd have to bind the the `window.innerWidth` value to the `[src]` value on your image tag. So something like this:

```
if (window.innerWidth > yourMediaQueryBreakpoint) {
  return this.loadSrcImg = 'your-image-url';
}
```

Then bind it in the template:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <img class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block d-lg-block img-fluid img-thumbnail" [src]="loadSrcImg">
  <img class="d-lg-none d-md-none img-fluid img-thumbnail" [src]="loadSrcImg">
</div>
```

I haven't tested it, but hope this helps.

Comment: Great. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this is in your `ts`. In that way you are reducing template compile time As there will be atleast two conditions.

I think you know how to do it, but for future user's sake, I am writing following piece of code.

TS

```
this.imgSrc = window.innerWidth > 768 ? ('api/thumbnail/' + auctionListItem.thumbnailId + '/400/300/thumbnail.jpg') : ('api/thumbnail/' + auctionListItem.thumbnailId + '/400/300/thumbnail.jpg');
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" [src]="imgSrc">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a media query in CSS and only use it for PRINT, and substitute a different URL for printing only. You may want to load it but hidden to make sure the onlyuseforprinting.jpg below is in the cache. Apparently this may not work reliably on Chrome unless the picture is in Cache.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
  #test:after {
    content: url("./images/onlyuseforprinting.jpg");
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of CSS tricks is that all pictures will be downloaded. Try below code to download only specific photo based on screen width.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="images/large.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="images/small.jpg">
  <img src="images/large.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

or try this

```
<img src="images/large.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px, 800px" srcset="images/small.jpg 480w, images/large.jpg 800w">
```